# How to use Chrome Frame ActiveX control

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, html5-canvas

Is there any sample about using Chrome Frame ActiveX control instead of Iframe? 
i need this because i can not use HTML5 canvas element in IE8 so that i tried chrome frame but it's not supported inside iframe.

I saw a post where it tells that Chrome Frame ActiveX control can be used instead of iframe.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-chrome-frame/2Jq-isAdi1k

Comment: Have you looked at [explorercanvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/)?

Answer (score 0):

Try serving up this code from a web server http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome_frame/host.html